# Sorting algorithms in data structures

Tags: sorting, data-structures

is there a free web resource that gives a quick list of 'Which data structure uses which sorting alorithm'?

Comment: Data structures don't use sorting algorithms.

Comment: Are you referring to any specific language or library implementation? What does this have to do with datetime? Usually a sorting algorithm is fairly generalized, and can be run independent of the data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the programming language.  Just assume that all data structures use the best sorting algorithm possible.

Trees are generally faster for searching and sorting (they often sort as they go, like a BST or red-black tree).  Lists are generally pretty lame.  Array structures generally use something like quick-sort for their sorting.

Do you have a specific application that needs to be super fast?  Post that and someone could suggest the best data-structure.  It really depends on the language, but you can generally assume that the people who designed the structures did it in the most efficient way possible.